# Mongo find by regex: return only matching string

Tags: mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

My application has the following stack:

Sinatra on Ruby -> MongoMapper -> MongoDB

The application puts several entries in the database. In order to crosslink to other pages, I've added some sort of syntax. e.g.:

> Coffee is a black, caffeinated liquid made from beans. {Tea} is made from leaves. Both drinks are sometimes enjoyed with {milk}

In this example {Tea} will link to another DB entry about tea.

I'm trying to query my mongoDB about all 'linked terms'. Usually in ruby I would do something like this: `/{([a-zA-Z0-9])+}/` where the `()` will return a matched string. In mongo however I get the whole record.

How can I get mongo to return me only the matched parts of the record I'm looking for. So for the example above it would return:

```
["Tea", "milk"]
```

I'm trying to avoid pulling the entire record into Ruby and processing them there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand.

```
db.yourColl.aggregate([
{
    $match:{"yourKey":{$regex:'[a-zA-Z0-9]', "$options" : "i"}}
},
{
    $group:{
        _id:null,
        tot:{$push:"$yourKey"}
    }
}])
```

If you don't want to have duplicate in `tot`use `$addToSet`

Comment: Thanks! This returns the entire field entry. So for my example it would return ```Coffee is a black, caffeinated liquid made from beans. {Tea} is made from leaves. Both drinks are sometimes enjoyed with {milk}```. Can we extract only ```Tea``` and ```milk``` ?

Comment: Maybe you can try with $or, or $and
`$match:{$or:[{'name':/Tea/i},{'name':{$regex:'milk',$options:'i' }}] }`

these are two ways for $regex

Take a look at this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: I have a similar problem. Has anyone found any solution? I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this problem is using the string aggregation commands to extract the StartingIndexCP, ending indexCP and substrCP commands to extract the string I wanted. Since you could have multiple of these {} you need to have a projection to identify these CP indices in one shot and have another projection to extract the words you need. Hope this helps.