# Autocomplete using mongodb (text, regexp)

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to implement an autocomplete feature on data base where the documents are large.The document model is as follows:

```
name:'book store 1',
address:'xyz'
...
books:[
{
    category:'some category'
    name:'book 1',
},
{
    category:'some book',
    name:'maybe',
},
]
```

The use case is that the user can search for the name of the book store, categories of books, or the names of the books. Since there is a overlap in the values of 'categories' and 'name'. I want to know where the query was matched. So if a user is searching for 'maybe' I want to know where it was matched so that I can indicate that this is a book name. I have looked at regexp but that does not seem to be very performant since it executes a whole collection scan and would defeat the purpose of autocomplete if it's not going to feel instant.

I have also looked at $text search but again, it does not tell me where the query was matched.

Comment: Could you please share the queries which you have tried . It may be possible to add some filter on those to get the desired result.

Comment: Yeah sure. So I first created a text index on the three fields, name, books.name, books.category. And then tried a simple `$search:'some'` query. It returns the whole document and does not tell where the pattern was matched. Also the `$regex: /some$/`. Same result.

Comment: this may helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866454/mongo-find-by-regex-return-only-matching-string