# Invalid Regex Mongoose

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB and I need to apply a regex to the find method using NodeJS Mongoose. The db contains elements such as:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("1234567899788675432454677"),
"nodes" : "[{\"name\":\"BINS\",\"oxygenation\":7.8,\"oxygenSaturation\":86,\"temperature\":13.3},{\"name\":\"CEST\",\"oxygenation\":4.6,\"oxygenSaturation\":52,\"temperature\":14.7},
"orp" : "0",
"chlorophyll" : "0",
"date" : "1615995776000",
"__v" : 0 }
```

and I need to go inside the nodes string to get all "name" values (in the example BINS and CEST). The regex that allows me to do it is

`/(?<=name\\\"\:\\")\w+(?=\\)/gm`

but I get errors when trying to use it both in mongo and Mongoose. For mongo I tried to escape all special characters:

`db.my_collection.find( { nodes: { $regex: "\(\?<=\\\"name\\\": \\\"\)\\w\+\(\?=\\\\\)" } } )`

but I get an empty result.

On Mongoose I tried several escaping such as the following, but I always get an error of invalid regex.

```
db.my_collection.find({ nodes : { $regex : '\(?<=name\\\\\\\"\\:\\\\\"\)\\w+\(?=\\\\\)' } }).
          exec(function (err, waterSensorsReadings) { ... });
```

Comment: Try `{ $regex : /(?<=name\\":\\")\w+(?=\\)/ }`  . Yes, no quotes/apostrophes around regexp

Comment: Mongoose returns an empty result, while mongo command line displays "uncaught exception: SyntaxError: invalid regexp group : "

Comment: What happens if you try some simple regex, like just `{ $regex: /name/ }` ? Does this produce any result?

Comment: Yes that one returns all the documents.

Comment: Ok, what about `/name":"/` ? If this works, then try `{ $regex : /(?<=name":")\w+(?=")/ }`

Comment: That one as well returns all the documents.

Comment: So the information is stored in the format `"name":"BINS"`, no backslashes at all. So you don't need them in the regex. `{ $regex : /(?<=name":")\w+(?=")/ }` should work

Comment: That one returns the SyntaxError as before.Every doc is in the form: { "_id" : ObjectId("60522f37ac6f04a757a761ac"), "nodes" : "[{\"name\":\"BINS\",\"oxygenation\":7.8,\"oxygenSaturation\":86,\"temperature\":13.3},{\"name\":\"RW3\",\"oxygenation\":6.6,\"oxygenSaturation\":74,\"temperature\":14.2}]", "salinity" : "17.1", "orp" : "0", "chlorophyll" : "0", "date" : "1615998775000", "__v" : 0 }

Comment: `db.my_collection.aggregate([{ $project: {  names: {  $regexFind: { input: "$nodes", regex: /name":"(\w+)/ }  }  } } ])`

Comment: That returns items such as ```{ "_id" : ObjectId("6052282fac6f049c0ba761a1"), "names" : { "match" : "name\":\"BINS", "idx" : 3, "captures" : [ "BINS" ] } }``` and ```{ "_id" : ObjectId("60522708ac6f0412e5a7619c"), "names" : null }```

Comment: Yes, the information you want is inside "captures"

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to get only the list of distinct values?

Comment: Probably this post is helpful: [MongoDB extract data from regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614401/mongodb-extract-data-from-regex)